# bitbucket git push stuck

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

Hi just set up a new bitbucket account and created a repo. I already have code in my local machine so I added the remote using `git remote add` now when i did `git push origin`, it prompted me to put password for the bitbucket account. After i entered the password, it just appears to be stuck. i ran `git push` on verbose mode but after I put the password it seems to be stuck.

Also I added my ssh key to bitbucket thinking that might help resolve the issue if it was authentication issue, but it still asks me for the password and get stuck after i provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I added my ssh key to bitbucket thinking that might help resolve the issue if it was authentication issue, but it still asks me for the password

It only adds a password if:

- it cannot find your public/private keys (~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)): check, if you are on Windows, if %HOME% is defined)
- the public key has been incorrectly copied over to bitbucket (typically with a newline in it)
- your remote (`git remote -v show`) is still configured with https address.

[image: ssh key]

Check out the [BitBucket Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git) page, and try cloning your repo using the ssh address.
(Note: for step 5 on that Help page, see also "[My .bashrc file not executed on Git Bash startup (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918285/my-bashrc-file-not-executed-on-git-bash-startup-windows-7)").

Comment: Thanks VonC,  Here is what I am seeing, from cygwin i am not able to push as it prompts me for password and gets stuck after that. I tried "GIT Bash" tool, and it still prompted me for password but i was able to do a push. It is strange as it works fine for github.

In Cygwin:
$ git pull \n 
Password for 'http://USERNAME@bitbucket.org': password
In Git Bash:
$ git pull   \n 
Password for 'bitbucket.org':

Comment: @bond cygwin? Could you rather use msysgit? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783906/git-under-windows-msys-or-cygwin/784743#784743)

Comment: btw, i also tried doing it via git plugin in eclipse, i get the following message:   http://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/repo.git: 301 Moved Permanently

Answer (score 22):

For me the problem is IPv4 needs to be used for bitbucket - using IPv6 hangs at trying to establish a connection to port 22 on the ipv6 address..

To fix this - edit your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and change

```
#AddressFamily any
```

to

```
AddressFamily inet
```

This forces ssh (and so git) to use ipv4 and not ipv6 sometimes

Comment: On ubuntu, mine ssh_config path was 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config

Comment: Worked! I have no idea why this is happening now. It worked a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Worked for me too! Not sure why this came up out of nowhere after years of everything working fine. My windows config file was in ~/.ssh/config

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to push a file over 10MB and the push got stuck. Fixed it by increasing the HTTP post buffer size

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```