# .bashrc not executed when starting GitBash

Tags: git, bash, ssh, git-bash

I'm following [this guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html#SetupSSHforGit-step-4-ssh-for-git), I've gotten to the part where I need to create the .bashrc file and it doesn't seem to execute when I restart GitBash. I've tried a few things including the answers on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918285/my-bashrc-file-not-executed-on-git-bash-startup-windows-7). I've also tried just having an echo in it for testing, which works when I execute it directly, but not when I start GitBash.

Comment: What functions you want to execute in `bashrc`?

Comment: The one on the guide that I referenced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by executing `git-bash -l -c bash` (the -l is a lower-case L). 
With that my $HOME/.bashrc gets executed immediately.
I am using PortableGit 2.5.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'll try this, but the way I fixed it was using a .bash_profile instead.

Comment: Yes, same thing did the trick for me too. Apparently something was recently changed so only ~/.bash_profile is sourced, and not ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 5):

As of Git 2.5.0 .bashrc no longer seems to be referenced to %USERPROFILE%\.bashrc.

But you can edit this file: "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc". It's a global file but it will have to do.

Also I think it's recommended to edit the files located at "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d" instead of creating .bashrc.

The files inside that folder read like:

> Some good standards, which are not used if the user
>
> creates his/her own .bashrc/.bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

`~/.bashrc` is not sourced by default, but `~/.profile` is...

you just create a `~/.profile` that sources your `~/.bashrc`

The below is the ~/.profile my cygwin came with that I copied to my into my git-bash's ~.

```
# To the extent possible under law, the author(s) have dedicated all
# copyright and related and neighboring rights to this software to the
# public domain worldwide. This software is distributed without any warranty.
# You should have received a copy of the CC0 Public Domain Dedication along
# with this software.
# If not, see <http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/>.

# base-files version 4.2-4

# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.

# The latest version as installed by the Cygwin Setup program can
# always be found at /etc/defaults/etc/skel/.profile

# Modifying /etc/skel/.profile directly will prevent
# setup from updating it.

# The copy in your home directory (~/.profile) is yours, please
# feel free to customise it to create a shell
# environment to your liking.  If you feel a change
# would be benificial to all, please feel free to send
# a patch to the cygwin mailing list.

# User dependent .profile file

# Set user-defined locale
export LANG=$(locale -uU)

# This file is not read by bash(1) if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
#
# if running bash
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
  if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then
    source "${HOME}/.bashrc"
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Git for Windows (v2.37.1) does not create ~/.profile, nor does .profile exist in /etc/skel/.profile or /etc/defaults/etc/skel/.profile. It **does** read a .bashrc file in %USERPROFILE%.

Answer (score 2):

Default git-bash with mingw64 on Win10 seem to not source `.bash_rc` and `.profile`.

Use `.bash_profile` instead.

The original question (and the website via the link provided) talk about `ssh-agent`. It is a good idea to clean up the agent on git-bash exit via `echo 'kill -KILL $SSH_AGENT_PID' >> .bash_logout`. git-bash seems to keep those agents running across sessions but one can not access them anymore because the variables are already gone. `.bash_logout` is sourced in git-bash

Tested on Win10 machine `$git version` gives `git version 2.20.1.windows.1`

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use the latest Git:

- uncompressed [`PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, and add C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit\bin to your `%PATH%`.
- then update your `%USERPROFILE%\.bashrc`
- finally, launch `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit\git-bash.exe`

If you are already in a bash session when modifyong the .bashrc, source it again to see if it does execute what you need.

```
source .bashrc
```

Comment: It was freshly installed.

Comment: @Zachrip was it installed through a msi setup, or through a simple uncompressed archived like the auto-extractable PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe?